# Iimplement required field validator in only one button

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

**How do i implement Required Field Validation in only one button.??**

I apply this in one page and it's work but in my page there are 2 buttons and both are 
check this validation.

Comment: What the buttons do you use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate=""/>` to validate only one button. Hope it helps